# Alternative to IPython with better autoreload

Tags: python, ipython

I'm looking for an alternative to IPython in the command line that addresses my two biggest gripes with iPython.

1) Auto-reload is great for functions, but I wish it also worked for the if name main statement, so that I wouldn't have to rerun the file constantly to capture changes here.

2) Since I do have to re-run the file in IPython to capture all changes, for some reason there are times where it does not run the most current version of the file after I have made changes to the file. This happens often enough that on a regular basis I have to exit and re-enter IPython to fix this.

Looking for a similar command line alternative to IPython or also open to any IPython hacks that fix these issues!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how long your code takes to run you might want to look at [Codi](https://github.com/metakirby5/codi.vim) (For vim but similar  plugin for other editors exists), or just use a second window with `watch python yourprogram.py`. It may cover your needs.

That being said autoreload can be a tricky process: You can't reload everything in Python, and IPython has a lot of safeguard of things it won't reload on purpose to avoid shooting yourself in the foot (one of the example that was added recently is Python 3.6 Enums). So it maybe that some of what you want to do can't be done, or is protected by a hidden option. It is just hard to tell without having a particular example.

Though, %autoreload and reload do not have a lot of users, and bug report are few. If you have an example of non-working code I'm pretty sure the IPython developers would be happy to get a bug report, and if fixable would be happy to guide you on how to fix things and submit a PR.

Have also a look at `%run -i` that might help you in not having to quit and reenter IPython.

Comment: Great thanks! Happen to know of an emacs version of something like Codi off the top of your head?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've seen it, but can't find the name from the top of my head. Sorry about that.